# Pymongo is not working in my kivy python android app

Tags: python, android, mongodb, kivy, pymongo

Why is my pymongo not connecting or returning anything in kivy app after successful compilation..??

I tried using pymongo in a threaded function in python to connect to the database, it is working perfectly fine in all desktop platforms but not working in the android app

Comment: Android != Linux. Pymongo probably is using a JDBC based connection. Please read [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)